# ErrorException in RegistrationController.php line 32: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController::Edit()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I am beginner of laravel 5.3 Now i am trying to edit user details

**My routes**:

```
 Route::get('/Edit/{id}','RegistrationController@Edit');
```

**View**

```
 <td>
         {{ Html::link('/Edit', 'Edit', array('id' => $user->id,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}} 
        </td>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function Edit($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
```

When i click Edit button i get an error like '**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**'. What is wrong with me?Please help me

Comment: $user=User::find($id);

Comment: @mizra-controller?

Comment: yes in controller you have to find id that will match with front end id

Comment: but still get NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: @MirzaObaid anything wrong in routes?

Comment: Route::get('edituser/{id}',[
        'as'=> 'edit_user',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@edit'
    ]);
that's how i used to write routes

Answer (score 1):

Your Error is that you are not passing id withedit route...

you have to do something like /Edit/{id}....

To do so one of the way is to use named route.

Since you are not passing the wild card i.e. $id in the link you are getting this error

In Route File Can you please Change to

```
Route::get('/Edit/{id}',['as'=>'EditUser','uses'=>'RegistrationController@Edit']);
```

And in View Change the Link to

```
{{ Html::link("route('EditUser',[$user->id])", 'Edit', array('id' => $user->id,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}
```

Hope this helps you. Ask if any doubt

Comment: -thanks but i get an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'EditUser' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_demo\resources\views\pages\viewdetails.blade.php)

Comment: might be because of some quote or brackets are missing..you can also do like your previous Html::link just by giving the id

{{ Html::link('/Edit/$user->id', 'Edit', array('id' => $user->id,'class' =>'btn btn-info'), true)}}

Comment: -get an error Undefined property: stdClass::$id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_demo\resources\views\pages\viewdetails.blade.php) what is wrong?

Comment: -localhost/laravel_demo/public/Edit/$user->s_no url i need 1,2,3 instead of $user->s_no :-(

Comment: sorry but i m not able to get what are you saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131482/discussion-between-rohit-shah-and-shanu-k-k).